# Add multiple variables inside of a Validator (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I have this (working) validator on my Laravel project

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  $insert_data1,
  [
      '*.emp_id' => "required|exists:users,company_id",
  ],
  [
      '*.emp_id.exists' => 'The selected :attribute is invalid. Employee does not exists!',
  ]
);

 if($validator->fails()){
    return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()])
    ->with('modal',$modal);
  }
```

Now I need to add another validation for a different variable like this

```
     $insert_data2,
     [
       '*.emp_id' => "required|exists:users,company_id",
     ],
     [
        '*.emp_id.exists' => 'The selected :attribute is invalid. Stakeholder does not exists!',
     ]
```

How can I add $insert_data2`inside of the`validator`?

Comment: you can not provide two array for a single validator instance. either prepare a new validator or merge your two arrays into one and use the combined collection for the validation.

Comment: Is it a good practice if I try to do different validator for `$insert_data1` and `$insert_data2` ?

Comment: if your two sets of data are different (different by source, structure, usage) you are encouraged to have separate validator. Actually, every set of data should have own validator instance. if all your validation rules and error messages are same, you can extract them and set as variables thus reusing in each validator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
$validation = array(
    'name' => 'required|max:60',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    // N Number of validation Rules
);

$messages = array(
    'name.required' => 'A Name is required',
    'name.max' => 'Name can only be of max 60 alphanumerics',
    'email.required' => 'Email address is required',
    'email.email' =>'Email must be a valid email'
    // N number of validation messages
);

$response = Validator::make($request,$validation,$messages);

if($response->fails()){
    //Your Logic
}
```